# RabbitMQ with Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, rabbitmq

I am writing a simple example in Camel for Rabbit MQ using Java DSL.

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("rabbitmq://localhost?exchange=logs&exchangeType=fanout")
                    .to("stream:out");
            }
        });

        context.start();
```

This example should read the messages and print them.

But I am getting following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[rabbitmq://localhost?exchange=logs&excha... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://localhost?exchange=logs&exchangeType=fanout due to: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:180)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:778)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2041)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1791)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1665)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1633)
    at com.test.app.App.initCamelContext(App.java:29)
    at com.test.app.App.main(App.java:15)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://localhost?exchange=logs&exchangeType=fanout due to: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:532)
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:71)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:190)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:106)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)
    at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:72)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:888)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:175)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1904)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:45)
    at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:27)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:123)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:512)
    ... 16 more
```

Following is my pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-rabbitmq</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>       
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Can somebody please help me in figuring out the missing part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to try something like

```
rabbitmq://localhost/logs?exchangeType=fanout
```

Answer (score 0):

wonhee's suggestion should fix your problem. Here's the explanation:

According to [RabbitMQ Component documentation](http://camel.apache.org/rabbitmq.html) the correct URL format is:

```
rabbitmq://hostname[:port]/exchangeName?[options]
```

There's no `exchange` option, but rather the exchange name is directly part of the path.

Answer (score 0):

The ExchangeName is not a option, it's part of URI path. I will update the RabbitMQComponent code throw more meaningful exception for it.